# Applying the Symmetry of DC Circuits

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits

While practicing for a notoriously difficult exam I have continued to come across questions like the following and despite my efforts to find resources on them, I can't seem to make sense of it.

**Given that switches $S_1$ and $S_2$ are closed, what is the current through branch ab and in what direction?**  I am very comfortable working with Kirchhoff's laws and the required mathematics.

[image: Circuit Diagram]

The answer schedule states that due the symmetry of the circuit you know that each lamp will receive $12\,\mathrm{V}$.  Can someone please help me understand the symmetry of the circuit and the implications that it has?  I'm less concerned about the actual calculations and more concerned about the physics theory behind it.

Also, when both $S_1$ and $S_2$ are closed - what type of circuit would this be considered to be (as in parallel or series)?  Instinctively it seems to be neither.

Answer (score 1):

The symmetry is that the lamps in the top half are the same as the lamps in the bottom half, albeit with a left/right switch.  When S2 is closed, it is clear that the left/right placing makes no difference, since a and b are at the same voltage.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, when both S1 and S2 are closed - what type of circuit would this
>   be considered to be (as in parallel or series)? Instinctively it seems
>   to be neither.

Or, it's both; there are two, series connected, identical pairs of parallel connected bulbs.

With S2 closed, the top two bulbs are in parallel (and so have identical voltage across) and the bottom two bulbs are in parallel (and so have identical voltage across).  But this does not imply that the voltage across every bulb is 12V.

Note that, with S2 closed, the top pair of bulbs can be switched with the bottom pair of bulbs *and the resulting circuit is indistinguishable (electrically) from the original circuit*.

It follows that the voltage across the top pair is identical to the voltage across the bottom pair and equal to$\frac{24}{2}V = 12V$